# modificar clave de array a partir de otro array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

tengo dos array, uno que contiene mis datos y otro que contiene los nuevas claves de mi array, donde tengo el campo index, que hace referencia al index del otro array donde deseo modificar la clave.

He estado tratando de realizarlo de la siguiente manera pero no pude conseguir lo que deseo

```js
var claves = [{c_camp: "c_prod",index: 0},
              {c_camp: "l_prod",index: 1},
              {c_camp: "k_medi",index: 5},
              {c_camp: "s_pre1",index: 2}]
var datos = [ {
               "0":"0000001",
               "1":"WANTAN FRITO",
               "2":"8,00",
               "3":"DIM SUM",
               "4":"FRITOS",
               "5":"001\r"
               },
              {
               "0":"0000002",
               "1":"ROLL DE ESPÁRRAGOS",
               "2":"10,00",
               "3":"DIM SUM",
               "4":"FRITOS",
               "5":"001\r"
              },
              {"0":"0000003",
                "1":"ROLL PRIMAVERA",
                "2":"10,00",
                "3":"DIM SUM",
                "4":"FRITOS",
                "5":"001\r"
              },
              {
               "0":"0000004",
               "1":"ALITAS BROASTER",
               "2":"6,50",
               "3":"DIM SUM",
               "4":"FRITOS",
               "5":"001\r"
              },
              {
               "0":"0000005",
               "1":"NABO ENCURTIDO",
               "2":"5,00",
               "3":"DIM SUM",
               "4":"FRITOS",
               "5":"001\r"
              },
              {
               "0":"0000006",
               "1":"SALCHIPAPA TUSAN",
               "2":"15,00",
               "3":"DIM SUM",
               "4":"FRITOS",
               "5":"001\r"
               },
              {
               "0":"0000007",
               "1":"SOPA WANTAN",
               "2":"9,50",
               "3":"SOPAS",
               "4":"SOPAS",
               "5":"001\r"
               }]

var resp = []
datos.forEach( function(valor1, indice1, array1){
    claves.forEach( function(valor2, indice2, array2){
        resp.push({[valor2.c_camp]:valor1[indice2]})
    })
})

console.log(resp);
```

lo que deseo obtener es de la siguiente manera:

```
[ {
                   "c_prod":"0000001",
                   "l_prod":"WANTAN FRITO",
                   "s_pre1":"8,00",
                   "k_medi":"001\r"
                   },
                  {
                   "c_prod":"0000002",
                   "l_prod":"ROLL DE ESPÁRRAGOS",
                   "s_pre1":"10,00",
                   "k_medi":"001\r"
                  },
                  {"c_prod":"0000003",
                    "l_prod":"ROLL PRIMAVERA",
                    "s_pre1":"10,00",
                    "k_medi":"001\r"
                  },
                  {
                   "c_prod":"0000004",
                   "l_prod":"ALITAS BROASTER",
                   "s_pre1":"6,50",
                   "k_medi":"001\r"
                  },
                  {
                   "c_prod":"0000005",
                   "l_prod":"NABO ENCURTIDO",
                   "s_pre1":"5,00",
                   "k_medi":"001\r"
                  },
                  {
                   "c_prod":"0000006",
                   "l_prod":"SALCHIPAPA TUSAN",
                   "s_pre1":"15,00",
                   "k_medi":"001\r"
                   },
                  {
                   "c_prod":"0000007",
                   "l_prod":"SOPA WANTAN",
                   "s_pre1":"9,50",
                   "k_medi":"001\r"
                   }]
```

**De antemano muchas gracias, y espero me puedan ayudar**
**-----------------------------------------------------**
**-----------------------------------------------------**
**-----------------------------------------------------**
**-----------------------------------------------------**
**-----------------------------------------------------**
**-----------------------------------------------------**
**-----------------------------------------------------**
**-----------------------------------------------------**
**-----------------------------------------------------**
**-----------------------------------------------------**
**-----------------------------------------------------**
**-----------------------------------------------------**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás insertando un nuevo elemento de arreglo en lugar de crear objetos separados.

En el primer ciclo inserta un objeto vacío al arreglo y, en el segundo, agrega cada una de las propiedades, según `claves` y usando el índice del primer ciclo para acceder a la posición correspondiente:

```js
var claves = [{c_camp: "c_prod",index: 0},
              {c_camp: "l_prod",index: 1},
              {c_camp: "k_medi",index: 5},
              {c_camp: "s_pre1",index: 2}]
var datos = [ {
               "0":"0000001",
               "1":"WANTAN FRITO",
               "2":"8,00",
               "3":"DIM SUM",
               "4":"FRITOS",
               "5":"001\r"
               },
              {
               "0":"0000002",
               "1":"ROLL DE ESPÁRRAGOS",
               "2":"10,00",
               "3":"DIM SUM",
               "4":"FRITOS",
               "5":"001\r"
              },
              {"0":"0000003",
                "1":"ROLL PRIMAVERA",
                "2":"10,00",
                "3":"DIM SUM",
                "4":"FRITOS",
                "5":"001\r"
              },
              {
               "0":"0000004",
               "1":"ALITAS BROASTER",
               "2":"6,50",
               "3":"DIM SUM",
               "4":"FRITOS",
               "5":"001\r"
              },
              {
               "0":"0000005",
               "1":"NABO ENCURTIDO",
               "2":"5,00",
               "3":"DIM SUM",
               "4":"FRITOS",
               "5":"001\r"
              },
              {
               "0":"0000006",
               "1":"SALCHIPAPA TUSAN",
               "2":"15,00",
               "3":"DIM SUM",
               "4":"FRITOS",
               "5":"001\r"
               },
              {
               "0":"0000007",
               "1":"SOPA WANTAN",
               "2":"9,50",
               "3":"SOPAS",
               "4":"SOPAS",
               "5":"001\r"
               }]

var resp = []
datos.forEach( function(valor1, indice1) {
    // Insertar un objeto vacío
    resp.push({});
    claves.forEach( function(valor2, indice2) {
        // Agregar cada propiedad
        // - resp[indice1] es el elemento actual
        // - [valor2.c_camp] es el nombre de la propiedad a crear
        // - valor1[valor2.index] debes usar el índice especificado en claves
        resp[indice1][valor2.c_camp] = valor1[valor2.index];
    })
})

console.log(resp);
```

Comment: gracias @Triby, ahora comprendo...